# I'm planning to become a very successful man and prove the world who I am and what I am capable of, but is it haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I am a student who has a very bad past(porn addiction, mental illness and a very bad person to my society) and now I want to prove the world what I am capable of by becoming successful. my question is, if I want to become successful and show my friends and family what I am capable of then am I seeking fame and if I am seeking fame is it haram?

Comment: How often will you spam the site with similar questions? Please delete one of your posts and wait maybe you'll get an answer. If anybody commented your question you should act upon a comment asking for clarification. We further expect a prior research effort to be shown which is missing in your post. (see [ask]).

Answer (score -2):

Bro you can see these scholares
https://images.app.goo.gl/ToyFh2ASHRwhwazk6
You can say that these are islamic scholars promoting deen but they to have fame.

And no were in quran or hadeed it is written "not to get fame".

So you can have fame.